# is this the correct way to read the message through kafka producer and push it to the topic

Tags: java, file, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have written this Kafka producer and reading a file from the desktop and then pushing the data in the file as the value and have generated key my self by adding one every time each line is read. Is it the correct way or I have done something I shouldn't have done?? Please need some advice.
I can see the message in my topic but each is related to a key so if I have a use case can I push any log data like this if I am reading it from outside. Can I use the log data as the value or is there completely different logic by which I should approach. 
Please Help

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;


public class SyncProducer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/ParseData.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        Properties properties  = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers","127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.setProperty("key.serializer",StringSerializer.class.getName()); // our key and values are String
        properties.setProperty("value.serializer",StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("acks", "1"); 
        properties.setProperty("retries", "3"); 
        properties.setProperty("linger.ms", "1"); 



        Producer<String,String> producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String,String>(properties);
        // these will go in random partition as we increment the key

        String line = " ";

        int key = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        //  System.out.println(line);

        ProducerRecord<String,String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String,String>("try_Buffered3Part",Integer.toString(key),line);
         key++;
         System.out.println(key);
        producer.send(producerRecord);

        }
        producer.close();
        System.out.println("exit");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine. You can choose to use null key if you are fine with random partition.

You may also want to look at logstash and kafka integration.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html

Comment: I see, thanks, Yep I know about the random key. thanks for sharing the links. so my next question is if I put them into HDFS how will it be read? like I can make a directory for each partition based on the key? and then I  might want only the value to put it into a hive table. Also, I know there is a Kafka connect which can put data to HDFS but how will I do programmatically. Right now I am struggling with the way to push data into hdfs through eclipse without creating a jar file and then deploying that jar file in the Hadoop cluster and then running it from there. I want to do from eclipse

Comment: where do you want to put the logs, kafka, hdfs or hive? If it is not kafka, either update the question or create a new one.

Comment: So let me rephrase it, I want to read logs from some source through Kafka and then write it to HDFS.

Comment: you can directly copy log files to hdfs as well. It will be much more efficient, especially after file rotation.

Comment: what if a lot of log files are generated and I need real-time ingestion of the data into HDFS. My concern here was that kafka would be better in scaling in terms of reading from many partitions

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the correct way

It is not clear your goals. Can you consume the data from the terminal? Then you're producing fine.

You can use Integers as the keys. Kafka has an IntegerSerializer

Using null as the key or excluding that parameter is the standard way to send data to a random partition and you'll not hit integer overload

> I want to read logs from some source through Kafka and then write it to HDFS.

If you just want log data into Hadoop, Fluentd or Logstash can accomplish this.

Before you start going to this path with Kafka, you should definitely pick a data format. Hadoop and Kafka prefer Avro or JSON rather than CSV, for example. Confluent has plenty of documentation on producing Avro into Kafka

You can use Kafka Connect HDFS Connector or Apache Nifi to get Kafka data into Hadoop. Don't reinvent the wheel writing your own consumer.

Comment: I see, I am actually new to the Kafka environment and is trying to learn the things step by step.  Thanks for letting me know , I did not know about the data format concept thanks for bringing light to that part I appreciate that.  What should I know for Nifi and how Can I get a grasp of that ?

Comment: Yes I am able to consume data from terminal

Comment: Nifi is just another open source software. But it has a GUI for you to drag and drop streaming processes... Some people prefer that over writing Kafka code and if you were using Hortonworks HDF Hadoop cluster, you could install it using a few clicks... If you only want to stay within the Kafka ecosystem, then see https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html